# Broken Pipe error on appcfg upload_data

Tags: google-app-engine

I have successfully download my data from datastore on my Mac OS X 10.8 (SDK 1.6). However when I'm using appcfg upload_data I get the following error; any idea ?

appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://localhost:8081/_ah/remote_api --filename=db_backup_2012_Nov_3

ERROR:

[INFO    ] Connecting to localhost:8081/_ah/remote_api [INFO    ] Starting import; maximum 10 entities per post ...........[INFO    ] Unexpected thread death: WorkerThread-2 [INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down... ........[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-2:  [ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-7:

[INFO    ] 350 entities total, 0 previously transferred [INFO    ] 190 entities (179958 bytes) transferred in 15.2 seconds [INFO    ] Some entities not successfully transferred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by limiting the number of threads to 1 when runnign appcfg upload_data:

appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://localhost:8081/_ah/remote_api --filename=db_backup_2012_Nov_3 --num_threads=1

The dev app server seems to be dropping threads. Perhaps because of having "threadsafe: no" in app.yaml!